# `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory not set` issue with Maven and IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I've spent quite some time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and hoping someone may be able to help.

My current setup is running Maven 3.3.3 (via homebrew) and Java 1.8.  IntelliJ 13 is the IDE of choice.

Running `mvn -version` results in the following:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-
22T12:57:37+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

which I believe means everything is OK, but when I go to my IDE and try to run a Maven project I get this error:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7539 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=13.1.3
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My M2_HOME var is set to `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec`, the same directory where homebrew installed it, and this also matches the IDE settings.

One search lead me to believe it may be something to do with Maven version and the IDE but I'm not convinced.  Can someone please shed some light on this please?

Comment: I've added your answer as a community wiki below.  In the future, if you've answered your question, please feel encouraged to answer it on your question.

Comment: Apparently tracked as [IDEA-137783](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137783)? But it seems to be a kind of regression in Maven, visible whenever you run for example `M2_HOME=/…/apache-maven-3.3.3 /…/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin/mvn …`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just in case you have that error again go to `Settings -> Maven -> Runner` and add

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
```

to VM Options.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I still have the installation on intellij13 with the error so I'll try this when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.  I'll still use IDEA 14 because, new and shiny but I'm glad there was a sensible solution. :)

Comment: I have a purchased license for IDEA 12, and the solution  works for me also. Thanks.

Comment: This may work, but it is not, what it should be. `maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory` property should point to the root of multi-module project, while `M2_HOME` is where Maven is installed. These are not the same thing. If it just needs to be set to anything, than you're fine. If it's used to locate some config files within the multi-project build, than you're not. Luckilly, `mvn` sets it, and IDEA 14+ does so as well. Maven, in general, has very loose (or lousy) definition of "root module" of your project.

Comment: If you are on Mac, go to IntelliJ > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner

Answer (score 7):

I had this wired issue while trying to build CAS Overlay Template using Maven. I could resolve it by adding the following environment variable:

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory
```

Comment: `export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory`
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

From the original question, the OP has solved their issue through this approach.

> I upgraded to IDEA 14, imported settings, created a new Spring project and it worked out of the box.

Comment: Although this was my solution, the one above is the accepted answer for IDEA 13.1 - just in case someone else stumbles across this post but can't upgrade.