# Setting M2_HOME

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea. Now I'm trying to set up new system and have came up with the next issue:

1. I've downloaded java, installed it, set `JAVA_HOME(C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_51)`, added to `PATH (C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin)`, checked from console `java -version` and `%JAVA_HOME%` - everything works fine (`java version "1.7.0_51"Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)`).
2. I've downloaded maven, installed it, set `M2_HOME(C:\Progra~2\Java\maven)`, added to `PATH(C:\Progra~2\Java\maven\bin)`, checked from console `mvn -version(Apache Maven 3.3.3 2015-04-22T14:57:37+03:00) Maven home: C:\Progra~2\Java\maven Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation Java home: C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251 OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"`) and enter `cd %M2_HOME%` - it goes there normally.

But when I try to do mvn -clean or -install or any other action from Intellij, it says:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: when re-reading question, I've noticed that sometimes system points to jre inside jdk, may be that is the reason ?

Comment: Restart your computer, all changes in PATH requires that. The only exception is when you will change it from cmd, then the changes are immediate.

Comment: @Tomek, yes, I've rebooted my computer

Comment: also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330577/maven-3-3-1-eclipse-dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-system-propery-is-not-s

Comment: @RC., nope, it's not related, because I use Idea and I've tried to add the arguments and nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the newest Maven 3.3.3 you have to take care of the new calling design. It changed from bat to cmd files. Your IDE probably isn't right now compatible to this new design. Try to take an older version of maven.

Maybe you have a look here too: [`-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory not set` issue with Maven and IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983683/dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-not-set-issue-with-maven-and-intellij)

Comment: hmmm... ok, I'll try an older version of maven. FIY, I'm using Idea 13 version, I'll check your version and answer ASAP

Comment: Normaly all IDE will call on windows the mvn.bat, but this was replaced by maven since the 3.3.3 version by a mvn.cmd file in bin dir. This was a problem to me with netbeans 8.0.2 too. Maven version 3.2.5 works for me.

Comment: thanks for your help! I've also unpacked 3.2.5 version and now everything works great! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ ships with a bundled Maven thus your settings and maven installation will not be picked up unless you explicitly specify Intellij to use your maven installation and not the bundled one.

You can verify it under: Maven Settings (use CTRL+SHIFT+A to find it if you can't locate it)
[image]